# Scrollable table has extra unwanted space in IE8

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

On a website with bootstrap.css installed I have the following scrollable table:

```
!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<table class="table table-condensed scrollable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4">
                        Application Event Log <br />
                        Time Source ... ...
                    </th>
                </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody id="testlogEvents" class="scrollable">  
               <tr id="13705" class="warning">
                 <td>10:23</td>
                 <td>IIS Express</td>
                 <td>3</td>
                 <td>null</td>
                </tr>
               <tr id="13704" class="warning">
                 <td>10:20</td>
                 <td>TestLog</td>
                 <td>4</td>
                 <td>null</td>
               </tr>      
             </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The css to make the table scrollable looks as follows:

```
.scrollable table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

.scrollable thead {
    text-align: left;
    display: table;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

    .scrollable thead tr {
        display: table-row;
        width: 100%;
    }

.scrollable tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

    .scrollable tbody tr {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .scrollable tbody tr {
        height: 18px;
    }

    .scrollable tbody td {
        padding: 1px 8px;
        width: 25%;
    }

.scrollable th, td {
    width: 25%;
}
```

The problem is this:

[image: Extra space]

(Ignore the not properly placed 'table header').

This extra space in IE8 is very much unwanted since I need all the space I can use.

Where does this extra spacing come from and how can I remove it?

Comment: Are you sure IE8 can handle things like `thead {display: table;` correctly? Otherwise you might be better off with the thead as a separate table, above the main one.

Comment: please add the actual HTML code that you render, instead of the placeholder `Dynamically generated table rows`.

Comment: Added the actual rows and the encoding.

Comment: @MrLister I am not sure about that but I did add selectivizr-min-js, css3-mediaqueries.js, html5shi.js, and respond.js which are all supposed to help fix html compatibility issues.

Comment: I will try a separate table on top. /Edit quick check makes no difference. It is something in css then.

Comment: I couldn't replicate in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/bh35L/ What's missing?

Comment: I cannot open your Fiddle. It crashes IE8. :)

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue. Culprit was clearfix on a surrounding element. Think is something to do with the content: '.' part.

Switching to a newer clearfix fixed it http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

You might want to change the title to a table caption, and then have all the header cells as separate TH cells. Or at very least:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="4">Application Event Log</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Source</th>
        <th>Count</th>
        <th>...</th>
    </tr>
<thead>
```

Comment: Clearfix is used as part of bootstrap. It makes sure a container will visually surround its floated children. Look for the .clearfix class in your code and the css

Comment: You know if you have a problem is you see ::before and ::after around the THEAD in the F12 source code